# Sonar-Qube FindBugs-PlugIn Fails at Test while building because of missing ASM Class

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

A good day to you stackoverflow community

I am trying to modify the FindbugsPlugin for SonarQube, but I cannot get it to compile. It always stops at this test:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.673 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest
canGenerateXMLReport(org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest)  Time elapsed: 1.268 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:156)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest.canGenerateXMLReport(FindbugsExecutorTest.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

canGenerateXMLReportWithCustomConfidence(org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.216 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:156)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest.canGenerateXMLReportWithCustomConfidence(FindbugsExecutorTest.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I already tried different versions of ASM, because it seems to be missing ClassAdaptor, but then it throws another error at me:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.115 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest
canGenerateXMLReport(org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.509 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:156)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest.canGenerateXMLReport(FindbugsExecutorTest.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

canGenerateXMLReportWithCustomConfidence(org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.28 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:156)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutorTest.canGenerateXMLReportWithCustomConfidence(FindbugsExecutorTest.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:891)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to pinpoint were I go wrong. Can anybody give me a hint please?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here (http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/), would be better to ask such question on the SonarQube Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube). But I've just double checked on my side that I was able to clone the "SonarQube Findbugs plugin" GitHub repository and build the project "mvn clean install" without any issue. So I suspect a potential corruption of your local Maven repository.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks for the hint.
Still even a fresh checkout is not building on my system with netbeans and I still have no clue why... ;(

Answer (score 0):

It seem I had a wrong version of the FindBugs.jar, so the ASM 3 of that jar interfered with the ASM 5 of Sonar.